# Unable to run usbmuxd as a service using systemd, but functional when executed through the terminal

Tags: systemd, ios

I'm trying to set up usbmuxd to run as a daemon, however I keep running into the following error :

```
    Dec  3 10:29:19 asci-kubu-NUC7i3BNH systemd[1]: asci-usbmuxd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec  3 10:29:19 asci-kubu-NUC7i3BNH systemd[1]: asci-usbmuxd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec  3 10:29:24 asci-kubu-NUC7i3BNH systemd[1]: asci-usbmuxd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec  3 10:29:24 asci-kubu-NUC7i3BNH systemd[1]: asci-usbmuxd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 46078.
Dec  3 10:29:24 asci-kubu-NUC7i3BNH systemd[1]: Stopped usbmuxd service.
Dec  3 10:29:24 asci-kubu-NUC7i3BNH systemd[1]: Started usbmuxd service.
Dec  3 10:29:24 asci-kubu-NUC7i3BNH usbmuxd[29950]: [0] Could not open lockfile
```

When I run it manually like so :

```
sudo usbmuxd -v --user usbmux --foreground
```

Everything is fine.

Here is my systemd .service file. I've read through the manual however I'm positive that I may have not set the correct capacities. I've verified the permissions/groups for usbmux user, usbmux is part of plugdev and sudo.

```
[Unit]
Description=usbmuxd service
Documentation=man:usbmuxd(8)

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/usbmuxd --user usbmux --systemd
PIDFile=/var/run/usbmuxd.pid
Restart=always
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
LimitNPROC=1

StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=asciusbmuxd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've dug around as best I could trying to find a solution. Thanks!

### UPDATE

**Using the unit file shipped with usbmuxd does not function**, and get the same error mentioned above I get when trying to pass the command parameters in ExecStart.

**Bundled unit file :**

```
[Unit]
Description=Socket daemon for the usbmux protocol used by Apple devices
Documentation=man:usbmuxd(8)

[Service]
ExecStart=@sbindir@/usbmuxd --user usbmux --systemd
PIDFile=@localstatedir@/run/usbmuxd.pid
```

When compiled, *@sbindir@* maps to */usr/local/sbin/usbmuxd* and *@localstatedir@ to /usr/local/var/run/usbmuxd.pid* which does not exist. I corrected it to */var/run/usbmuxd.pid*.

Whether it's my unit file, or the bundled one removing, 
    --user usbmux --systemd 
allows it to run correctly.

Trying to set usbmux via the unit file rather than via ExecStart also fails.

Syslog tells me the following :

```
Oct  4 10:52:19 potato asciusbmuxd[17327]: [10:52:19.635][0] Failed to drop privileges (cannot set supplementary groups)
```

When I remove User reference, the service starts correctly but I get, and I cannot execute ideviceinfo or use anything related to lockdownd :

```
usbmuxd[17462]: [2] chmod(/var/lib/lockdown, 02775) failed: Operation not permitted
```

I should note that I am forced to compile it, as I have OS restrictions and must use 16.04, I require a usbmuxd version that is more recent than available in the repos.

My systemd version is 229.

Comment: Why are you not using the service unit file that comes with usbmuxd?

Comment: Wait a sec, there's a unit file that's bundled in? I'm still learning, and I don't get why my question got downvoted... I legitimately needed some help. 



I just checked the source.. I found : 

[Unit]
Description=Socket daemon for the usbmux protocol used by Apple devices
Documentation=man:usbmuxd(8)

[Service]
ExecStart=@sbindir@/usbmuxd --user usbmux --systemd
PIDFile=@localstatedir@/run/usbmuxd.pid

I'll go try that. Thanks